# is there any way to look up external CDI bean or EJB session using its name?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi

i was working with jboss Seam framework to invoke  seam components like that Component.forName("exampleBean").newInstance();  as "exampleBean" the  name of the bean that i have to look up.
But recently i migrate into JEE6 and i'm loooking for the way to look up EJBs or CDI beans without using JNDI context?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Deltaspike probably.

*Resolving a simple contextual instance:
MyBean myBean = BeanProvider.getContextualReference(MyBean.class, false);
Pass true as second argument, if you look for an implementation of the given interface and an implementation isn’t required or it isn’t required that there is an instance with the given qualifier (see the qualifier example for further details)[...]*

http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/core.html#_beanprovider

Answer (score 0):

To look up a CDI bean by name, one can use the [BeanManager's getBeans method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html#getBeans(java.lang.String)) combined with the resolve method of the same class. Here's an example of how to use this:

```
    @Inject BeanManager beanManager;  //inject bean manager into the class

    void someMethod() {
        Set<Bean<E>> possibleBeans = beanManager.getBeans("aBeanName");
        Bean<E> bean = (Bean<E>) beanManager.resolve(possibleBeans);        
        E instance = beanManager.getContext(bean.getScope()).get(bean, beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the BeanManager will solve you problem 
you can take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html#getBeans(java.lang.String))